# Unable to submit an edit form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I thought it would be a good idea and try to implement an edit form that takes place of the spot in the table with the data you are trying to edit. I have not been able to get my form to submit while the create form works the same and functions properly, here is the code that I need help with.
This is the partial view of the edit form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PublisherEditForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PublisherID)
    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublisherName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublisherName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublisherName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>

    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>

    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>

    <td>
        <input id="saveUpdate" type="submit" value="Update Publisher" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </td>
}
```

Here is the Ajax that I am using to try and submit the form:

```
$('#PublisherEditForm').submit(function (e) {
        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
        e.preventDefault();
        $('MessageContent').
        html("<div class='alert alert-info'>Please Wait...</div>");
        $.ajax({
            url: "@Url.Action("AjaxEdit", "PublishersEF")",
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#MessageContent').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Your record was updated!</div>");
                $('#PublisherEditForm')[0].reset();
                var row =
                    '<tr><td>' + data.PublisherName +
                    '</td><td>' + data.City +
                    '</td><td>' + data.State +
                    '</td><td> <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "PublishersEF")">Refresh View</a></td></tr>';
                $('#Publisher' + data.PublisherID).replaceWith(row);
                console.log('success');
                $('PublisherEdit').hide();
                $('#MessageContent').html('<div class="alert alert-warning">There was an error processing your update, please try again or contact the site administrator</div>');
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log('error');
                $('#MessageContent').html('<div class="alert alert-warning">There was an error processing your update, please try again or contact the site administrator</div>');
            }
        });
    });
```

I have tried to put a console.log inside both the success and error and I did not see either of them in the console

EDIT: here is the C# method:

```
[HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult PublisherEdit(int id)
    {
        Publisher publisher = UnitOfWork.PublisherRepository.Find(id);
        return PartialView(publisher);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult PublisherEdit(Publisher publisher)
    {
        UnitOfWork.PublisherRepository.Update(publisher);
        UnitOfWork.Save();
        return Json(publisher);
    }
```

I can confirm the UnitOfWork functions correctly. All this function does is connect to the database and updates/saves the information. This has worked in previous versions

Comment: Please post c# method.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console ?

Comment: No errors in the console, in the ajax function I put a console.log in both the success and error and nothing has been showing up in the console. I know when I pull up the debug tools it shows the closing form tag is before any of the text boxes, however the create form appears the same and functions as it should

Comment: Your c# method is hitted ?

Comment: The get is fine, since the form doesn't submit it is not triggering the Post which means it doesn't save the changes made

Comment: If it doesn't trigger post method then you should receive 404 error in your console.

Comment: Be sure your HTML is well formed.

Comment: All the html is fine, this is interesting though. If I place the script in the partial view the form submits (or rather goes to the home index view) and does not update the information. I know the problem is not the UnitOfWork, my edit forms on other tables work fine and use this same code. No errors are appearing in the debug window. The only thing I am seeing is the ID of the publisher which I put in there to make sure it is passing the right value

Comment: is this correct? Url.Action("AjaxEdit", "PublishersEF")

Comment: I changed it back to PublisherEdit, I was playing around with the naming of the method and seeing if that was causing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten it to work. Interestingly I could not keep the script tag in the index view. I had to put it back in the partial view (for some reason it wasn't working before). Here is the updated partial:

```
@model cStoreMVC.DATA.EF.Publisher

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "PublisherEditForm" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PublisherID)
    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublisherName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublisherName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublisherName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>

    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>

    @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.State, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
    <td>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.State, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.State, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </td>

    <td>
        <input id="saveUpdate" value="Update" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </td>
}
@section scripts{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
<script>
$('#PublisherEditForm').submit(function (e) {
    var formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#MessageContent').html("<div class='alert altert-info'>Please Wait...</div>");
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("PublisherEdit", "PublishersEF")",
        type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('it worked');
        $('#MessageContent').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>Your Item Was Updated!!!</div>");
        $('#PublisherEditForm')[0].reset();


        var row =
            "<tr class='newRow'><td>" + data.PublisherName +
            '</td><td>' + data.City +
            '</td><td>' + data.State +
            '</td><td>Refresh to view options </td></tr>';
        $("#Publisher-" + data.PublisherID).replaceWith(row).find('tr.newRow:last');
    },
    error: function (e) {
        console.log(it);
        $('#MessageContent').html("<div class='alert alert-warning'>There was an error. Please try again or contact the site administrator.</div>");
    }
});
});
</script>
```

I have found out that forms and table rows do not work together nicely(this might be why the form did not submit) if you want it to be horizontal I was told and I can confirm it works use `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;`. If you want to display it in a table like I did remove all the table data tags from the form itself and wrap the whole form in a table data tag. It doesn't look the best but it works! For those with future issues like this I hope this helps!

Comment: Found this interesting. This works, however in debug tools to does not put in as table data and if I try it won't submit

Comment: Scripts NEVER go in partials, and `@section scripts{` is not even supported in partials so `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")` is not even executed. And its `var formData = $(this).serialize();` (not `.serializeArray();`)

Answer (score 0):

I've face that kind of issues, and I resolved it doing this:

Declare your button as follows:

`<input id="saveUpdate" value="Update Publisher" type="button"                                                                     class="btn btn-primary" />`

And add this js function:

```
$("#saveUpdate").on('click', function() {
    try {
        var currentForm = $("#PublisherEditForm");
        currentForm.append("<input type='hidden' name='flagButton' 
        id='flagButton' value='Publish' >");
        $(currentForm).submit();
    } catch (e) {

    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still no luck, I tried putting a console.log in the try and catch and nothing showed up in the console